# How can I create a function inside an $.click (jquery) that uses an id from the $.click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

So, as I think, my title is not pretty understandable.
I have this jquery code:

```
$("img.slideimg").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("img.previewimg." + id).css({"display": "block"});
    $("div.imgpreview").css({"display": "flex"});

    function slideDo(n) {
        var i;
        var aux = id - 1 + n;
        var slidesp = document.getElementsByClassName("previewimg");
        if (aux > slidesp.length) {aux = 1}
        if (aux < 1) {aux = slidesp.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slidesp[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slidesp[aux-1].style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

The problem is that the browser console output is this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: slideDo is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:85)
```

My problem is that I want to create a function that uses an variable from the $("img.slideimg").click event. This variable is id = $(this).attr('id'); so I thinked of creating the function inside it. Apparently it doesn't work like this so I need a little help.

Sorry if you don't understand me. I'm pretty new to this kind of coding :(

HTML where i use slideDo

```
<div class="middle">
  <a class="prev" onclick="slideDo(-1)"> ❮ </a>
  <div class="imglink">
    <img src="img/dailyui/008.png" class="previewimg 1">
    <img src="img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="previewimg 2">
    <img src="img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="previewimg 3">
    <img src="img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="previewimg 4">
  </div>
  <a class="next" onclick="slideDo(1)"> ❯ </a>
</div>
```

So what I want to do:
I have a slideshow and when I click on one of the pictures, a modal with the pictures will show up. Then here I have again another buttons for next / previous picture but they doesn't seems to work. Here is the demo website of my code: beta.eduardstefan.com

Comment: Why is the function inside of the click? AKA, it is not global scope.

Comment: Where do you call `slideDo()`?

Comment: @epascarello Apparently so it can use the `var` variable.

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Show us some relevant html structure.

Comment: @charlietfl I added html in the post right now

Comment: what about the `img.slideimg` html?

Comment: @charlietfl I added the link to the whole website with the code. Can you check from this or should I add it here? *Also sorry if there is not the place where should I answer you. Is my first time on stackoverflow

Comment: questions need to be self contained....links rot and it is a lot of effort to go poking around trying to figure out what is what. You are doing fine so far. Will help to see the rest of the question relevant html structure to get good answer

Comment: @charlietfl In other ways can I ask this: does you know how to add multiple slideshows on a single page with simple preview mode(just photo itself, next, previous buttons and close) ? Like a plugin or something? Maybe I'll smack my head getting this done but in case I will can't, I would like to have a backup plan :)

Comment: There are many many many plugins easily found on the web. Pick one based on features needed but also very importantly based on good documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the name `slideDo` is just the click function, but it appears you're trying to call it from the global scope (the `onclick` attribute of an anchor). You need to assign the function to a global variable.

```
var slideDo = function() {}; // initially does nothing

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.slideimg").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("img.previewimg." + id).css({"display": "block"});
        $("div.imgpreview").css({"display": "flex"});

        slideDo = function(n) {
            var i;
            var aux = id - 1 + n;
            var slidesp = document.getElementsByClassName("previewimg");
            if (aux > slidesp.length) {aux = 1}
            if (aux < 1) {aux = slidesp.length}
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slidesp[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slidesp[aux-1].style.display = "block";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sure looks ugly just to access an id that could probably easily be obtained with a traverse or active class or other self contained means

Comment: @charlietfl I agree, this isn't how I would do it. But I don't feel like completely redesigning his application for this answer.